# Assert element no longer present

Tags: webdriver

Using webdriver and testing an application built using gwt. I want to first assert that an element becomes present. This element is loaded dynamically and it is not trivial to test. However I need to assert that the element becomes no longer present. As in it is no longer present in the dom. My original approach to this is to build an ExpectedCondition and then wait for the condition i.e.

```
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.findElements(By.cssSelector(someCSSpath)).size() == 0;
    }};

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(e);
```

I would have expected that would have waited for 15 seconds for the element to disappear from the dom, I would expected that it would poll every 500 milis. I would expect that at every poll the bool would be false as the element would be found until such time as it disappears and at which point the condition becomes true. What I find in my output is that indeed it polls every 500 milis however once the condition becomes true I actually wait for an entire minute before moving onto the next step. This seems incorrect behavior, am I missing something? Any suggestions?

Comment: Per the doc [JavaDoc for WebDriverWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) this particular constructor has 2 parameters, the second one is a long and is in seconds.

Comment: Do you have Implicit wait specified? If yes, you may need to switch that off for this condition, since findElements() will wait (for the duration of Implicitly wait) for the element to be there at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use : `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(..)` as to check that the element was successfully removed from DOM. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set "implicitlyWait" to 60 seconds?

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When object disappears it will wait on "findElements" method 60 seconds before it returns.

I recommend to set "implicitlyWait" to 0 before running "wait.until(e);" method and then set it back to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a handle on WebElement you can use this.

`new WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf( webElement ));`